# for a given sub-vector space there are different supplementary

Tags: vector-spaces

I don't understand why in general, if we have a $\mathbb{R}$ vector space of dimension $n \geq 1$, and a sub-vector space space $F$ of $E$ then $F$ don't have a unique supplementary ?

Do you have example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of a sub-vector space $F$ that has more than $1$ supplementary ?

Thank you !

Comment: Yes. Take the span of the first unit vector, then you can either choose the span of the second unit vector or the span of the vector with a 1 in both entries.

Comment: Thank you, I think i was having a hard time understanding the difference between supplemntary and complementary... feels bad